# Problem k-subvector using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a vector V of n integers and an integer k, k <= n, you want a subvector (a sequence of consecutive elements of the vector ) of maximum length containing at most k distinct elements.

The technique that I use for the resolution of the problem is dynamic programming.
The complexity of this algorithm must be O(n*k).

The main problem is how to count distinct elements of the vector. as you would resolve it ?

How to write the EQUATION OF RECURRENCE ?

Thanks you!!!.

Comment: You may want to read about bit vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you would insist on `O(n*k)`, this can be solved in `O(n)` with 'sliding window' approach.

1. Maintain current 'window' `[left..right]`
2. At each step, if we can increase `right` by 1 (without violating 'at most k disctint elements' requirement), do it
3. Otherwise, increase `left` by 1
4. Check whether current window is the longest and go back to #2

Checking whether we can increase `right` in #2 is a little tricky. We can use hashtable storing for each element inside window how many times it occurred there.

So, the condition to allow `right` increase would look like

```
hash.size < k || hash.contains(V[right + 1])
```

And each time `left` or `right` is increased, we'll need to update hash (decrease or increase number of occurrences of the given element).

I'm pretty sure, any DP solution here would be longer and more complicated.

Comment: I understand that the problem can be solved in O(n),but the approach that I use to solve the problem is that of dynamic programming (because it requires the text), Why should I use  hashtable in this approach

Comment: @Antony

Dynamic programming is a variant of recursion that reuses generated subresults (often multiple times).
Since any algorithm can be converted from an iterative one into a recursive one, it should be no problem for you to do so...

Comment: @Nubok: is not precisely so, the dynamic programming is necessary to characterize the sub-optimal, recursively define the value of the optimal solution (using the equation of recurrence), provide an algorithm that calculates the value of the optimal solution, and finally the algorithm for the construction of an optimal solution.It is not a simple conversion of an iterative algorithm to a recursive

Comment: @Antony I'm curious, where did you find this 'text'? Anyway, good luck with your search.

Comment: @Antony It means, I can't help you anymore.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid as some form of Dynamic Programing Algorithm. +1.

Comment: I agree that the solution is valid, but the post title says another thing : "Problem k-subvector using DYNAMIC PROGRAMMING"

Comment: @ANtony: Ok, give me a precise definition of Dynamic Programming under which this solution fails to be one.

Comment: There is no a definition of the optimal solution, that is ,the definition of the substructure optiman and does not describe how to compute recursively the value of the optimal solution .The definition of dynamic programming have given above ,then at the end of the response is written :"I'm pretty sure, any DP solution here would be longer and more complicated."

Comment: @Antony: I think that Nikita is mistaken there. What he has here is a dynamic programming solution. It computes optimal solutions for sub-arrays of the main array. Just not all of them. If you need help in your homework done in a specific way, why don't you copy the homework verbatim and show your working and the parts where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0):

> the main problem is how to count distinct elements of the vector. as you would resolve it?

If you allowed to use hashing, you could do the following

```
init Hashtable h
distinct_count := 0
for each element v of the vector V
    if h does not contain v (O(1) time in average)
        insert v into h (O(1) time in average)
        distinct_count := distinct_count + 1
return distinct_count
```

This is in average O(n) time.

If not here is an O(n log n) solution - this time worst case

```
sort V (O(n log n) comparisons)
Then it should be easy to determine the number of different elements in O(n) time ;-)
```

<strike>I could also tell you an algorithm to sort V in O(n*b) where b is the bit count of the integers - if this helps you.</strike>

Here is the algorithm:

```
sort(vector, begin_index, end_index, currentBit)
    reorder the vector[begin_index to end_index] so that the elements that have a 1 at bit currentBit are after those that have a 0 there (O(end_index-begin_index) time)
    Let c be the count of elements that have a 0 at bit currentBit (O(end_index-begin_index) time; can be got from the step before)
    if (currentBit is not 0)
        call sort(vector, begin_index, begin_index+c)
        call sort(vector, begin_index+c+1, end_index)
```

Call it with
vector = V
begin_index = 0
end_index = n-1
currentBit = bit count of the integers (=: b)-1.

This even uses dynamic programming as requested.

As you can determine very easily this is O(n*b) time with a recursion depth of b.

Comment: yes, but the resolution should I use dynamic programming. then definition of recurrence equation and then algorithm for calculating the optimal solution.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem. We're supposed to find subsequence, not count the amount of distinct elements in the whole sequence.

Comment: @Nikita Rybak

Perhaps you are right - but since Antony told this to be his main problem (does he see a solution that I don't see?) I'm willing to give it. :-)